# Is it possible to include in allure report the specflow features info

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nunit, specflow, allure

I am trying to include in allure report the specflow features content.

To do it I am following the tutorial of the [following page.](http://automatedtester.science/test-reports-with-visual-studio-nunit-and-allure/)

What is missing in the turorial is how to include the information of the specflow features files in the report generated by allure. Would it be possible to include this info?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You should check `@Issues` and `@Issue` Allure reports annotation.

In C# it will be propably `[Issues]` and `[Issue]` attributes.